# Will I loose data or software when upgrading the kernel and/or OS version?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, software-installation

I have a doubt. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. If I change my kernel version, will any data be lost? I've installed some software packages, will those still be present after updating my kernel?

And the same question for upgrading to a new OS (14.04). Will any data or software be lost if I upgrade to 14.04?

Comment: That is why you make a copy of your personal data before you start. BTW: you tagged it 13.04?!

Comment: @AvinashRaj why yes? That will depend on what packages have been installed. I see no reason why _data_ would be lost.

Comment: I think after a version upgrade, previously installed packages would be lost.

Comment: Answers on both: possibly. It depends mostly on the skills of the person installing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading shouldn't cause any data loss. However, you should always backup your data, especially before doing such things. Also, the packages you installed normally get updated when upgrading to a newer Ubuntu release, but nothing more. Some repositories might get disabled, can't say why.

Updating the kernel doesn't touch your files (of course, why should it do that?).

In fact, upgrading to a newer kernel or Ubuntu release is extremely easy and **if you keep your data backed up** also pretty safe.

Comment: "Some repositories might get disabled, can't say why" PPA's get disabled cuz not all PPA's will have the new OS yet (so could run into a 404).

Answer (score 0):

Updating kernel shouldn't cause any problems unless you've installed some **kernel modules** yourself (NVIDIA's or AMD's drivers for example).

Upgrading Ubuntu updates your kernel and PPAs, so you might lose some applications, if your PPAs aren't compatible with 14.04 yet. Before upgrading, **make sure you aren't using drivers downloaded from self added PPAs (such as Oibaf's one) or NVIDIA/AMD websites**. Drivers installed from official Ubuntu repositories (eg. these in Software and updates > Additional drivers) are fine.

Your files are safe, though doing backup before upgrading anything is a good idea.